# Generic std::function member

Tags: c++, windows, templates, callback, functor

I have a class that uses EnumWindows. Since that requires a callback i wrapped it into a nice little tool class similar to this:

```
Class Tools
{
public:
    template<typename WinFunctor>
    std::vector<HWND> FindWindow(WinFunctor Functor);

private:
    BOOL EnumWindowMsgProc(HWND hWnd);
    static BOOL CALLBACK FreeWndProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        Tools* pThis = (Tools*)lParam;
        return pThis->EnumWindowMsgProc(hWnd);
    }
    std::vector<HWND> m_Windows;
    /*Need to store WinFunctor Here*/
}

BOOL Tools::EnumWindowMsgProc(HWND hWnd)
{
    if(/*Call WinFunctor Member here*/)
    {
        m_Windows.push_back(hWnd);
    }
    return TRUE;
}
template<typename WinFunctor>
std::vector<HWND> Tools::FindWindow(WinFunctor Functor)
{
    m_Windows.clear();
    EnumWindows(FreeWndProc, (LPARAM)this);
    return m_Windows;
}
/*Windows Callbacks must be free (not a class member), 
so I define a static method (free) and forward to my    
member function(not free)*/
```

Example of a WinFunctor:

```
bool EnumByWindowName(HWND WinHandle,const std::wstring& WinName)
{
    wchar_t Temp[1024]{L'\0'};
    GetWindowText(WinHandle, Temp, 1024);
    if (std::wstring(Temp).compare(WinName.c_str()) == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Example of desired interface

```
Tools ToolInst;
auto Windows=ToolsInst.FindWindow(EnumByWindowName(std::placeholders::_1,"Notepad-Untitled"));
```

I somehow need to store the Functor as a member so that i can call it later in the callback, BUT I can't just template the class because this would require me to create a new tools instance each time i wanted to search for a different window (and the tools class hold many more functions than just EnumWindows).The Functor must always accept an hWnd but can then act on that data using whatever it wants, and may pass other args required to act on that (such as WindowName sting).Is there anyways to store the functor and not have to create a new instance of the class each time. Thanks for any help

Comment: Using `std::function` and `std::bind()` might come in handy for such use case.

Comment: isn't `std::function` generic *enough*?

Comment: if i knew the functor the caller was going to use AND they only used one type of functor then yes i could use std::function alone but i can't figure out how to accept a general functor. I.E functor should do "Here's a hWnd, you tell me how to determine if it's the right one, and ill push it into my vector"

Comment: well, take the functor as you do, store it in `std::function<bool(HWND)>`, and pass one in with `std::bind(&EnumByWindowName, std::placeholders::_1, "Notepad-Untitled")` OR as `[] (HWND hWnd) { return EnumByWindowName(hWnd, "Notepad-Untitled"); }`

Comment: That appears to work, it at least compiles ill post back if it works properly. Looks like i was to eager to use templates.

Comment: This worked exactly like i wanted, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution As posted by Piotr S.

```
Class Tools
{
public:
    typedef std::function<bool(HWND)> WinFunctor;
    std::vector<HWND> FindWindow(const WinFunctor& Functor);

private:
    BOOL EnumWindowMsgProc(HWND hWnd);
    static BOOL CALLBACK FreeWndProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        Tools* pThis = (Tools*)lParam;
        return pThis->EnumWindowMsgProc(hWnd);
    }
    std::vector<HWND> m_Windows;
    WinFunctor m_WinFunctor;
}

BOOL Tools::EnumWindowMsgProc(HWND hWnd)
{
    if(m_WinFunctor(hWnd))
        m_Windows.push_back(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}

std::vector<HWND> Tools::FindWindow(const WinFunctor& Functor)
{
    m_Windows.clear();
    m_WinFunctor=Functor;
    EnumWindows(FreeWndProc, (LPARAM)this);
    return m_Windows;
}
```

Interface:

```
auto Windows = m_Tools.FindParentWindow(std::bind(&WinEnumFunctors::EnumByWindowName, std::placeholders::_1, L"Some WindowName"));
```